# jQuery ajax form to upload image & submit form & save values in MySQL db

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have an HTML form, which i am submitting via jquery.$ajax();

Form has to:
1. Upload image, to  a directory , with ERROR-CHECKS
2. Save image-path to mysql DB
3. Insert other 2 form VALUES: input+select value to DB
4. Alert - success, on form submission if both image gets uploaded & values submitted to DB successfully

M TIRED OF TRYING USING JSON:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'submit.php',
type: 'POST',
data: data,
cache: false,
dataType: 'json',
processData: false, // Don't process the files
contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 

// lots of bullshit code 

}

});
```

Any fresh full working code ? which can do these tasks ?
I already posted 2 questions seeking help with JSON, but no one seems to agree, battling with JSON.

//////////////////////// HTML FORM CODE ///////////////////////////

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="fb_form" id="fb_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="sm" border="1px solid #CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><strong>Facebook</strong></td>
<td><input type="file" name="fb_icon" style="border: solid 1px #90D8CF;"
placeholder="Upload Image"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fb_link" style="border: solid 1px #90D8CF;"
placeholder="Paste redirect link"></td>
<td>
<select name="show_fb" class="myselect">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<option value="1">Show</option>
<option value="0">Hide</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<button class="myButton" type="submit" id="fb_submit">UPDATE</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form><!--------FB Form ends here------------>


</body>
</html>
```

///////////////////// BASIC MYSQL DB STRUCTURE CODE IN submit.php //////////////////////

```
$filename_wpath =  $imagepath;
    $fb_link = $_POST['fb_link'];
    $show_fb = $_POST['show_fb'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblbasicheader`(fldFB_image, fldFB_link, fldHideShow)
                VALUES('$filename_wpath','$fb_link','$show_fb')";

mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Any guesses, what should be good code inside : $.ajax();
Thanks tons in Advance, for being a code-fighter :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search lead me to this [demo app](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) using jQuery.

P.S: If Google can't find it, you are probably searching it wrong.